# How to run code on all possible combination of 3 strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 strings:

```
strand1 = "something"
strand2 = "something else"
strand3 = "something else again"
```

I want to run a few functions on each possible arrangement of those 3 strings, e.g.:

Case 1:

```
strand1 = "something else again"
strand2 = "something"
strand3 = "something else"
```

Case 2

```
strand1 = "something else"
strand2 = "something else again"
strand3 = "something"
```

etc ...

How would I do that elegantly in Python? I considered putting the strings in an array and using `itertools` but it seems to cut the strings at each iteration.

Another thing to consider is that the strings are stored in an object. For example I call `strand1` by typing

```
strand1.aa
```

Thanks for any help, I hope that the question is clear.

Comment: Look at the itertools library, try to do it by yourself

Comment: What do you mean by the strings were cut at each iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`itertools` is the right place to look. Have you tried `itertools.permutations`?

Check out the [documentation for it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations).

Something on the ways of `itertools.permutations(iterable)` will give you a generator of permutations, then you could use a for loop to process each permutation.

```
from itertools import permutations

# Any iterable will do. I am using a tuple.
for permutation in permutations(('a', 'b', 'c')):  # Use your strings
    print(permutation)  # Change print() to whatever you need to do with the permutation
```

This sample produces

```
('a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'b')
('b', 'a', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a')
('c', 'a', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'a')
```

Comment: Should've posted a sample code demonstrating the application of your answer .. just to be more complete..

Comment: @IronFist I agree. If I don't solve his problem explicitly there is no issue with it. There it is. I've passed the permutations as a tuple as we already have an example of the star operator.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`itertools.permutations`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters). If function has multiple argument, you may pass them via [splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters).

```
import itertools

def f(a, b, c):
    print(a, b, c)

# o = get_my_object()
# seq = [o.a, o.b, o.c]
seq = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
for perm in itertools.permutations(seq):
    f(*perm)
```

Output:

```
s1 s2 s3
s1 s3 s2
s2 s1 s3
s2 s3 s1
s3 s1 s2
s3 s2 s1
```

Comment: What's the purpose of function `f(a, b, c)` ?...Couldn't you just in the `for` loop do `print(*perm)` ?

Comment: OP said that he want to call some function on all permutations. I wanted explicit user function instead of builtin to show how splat operator works.

Comment: LOUD AND CLEAR .. :)